# How to determine if a write operation is successful using NSFileHandle?

Tags: xcode, macos, file, nsfilehandle

The method `-writeData:` of `NSFileHandle` class returns nothing. Is there any way for us to determine whether the operation is successful or not? Or I should use other way to save my data?

Comment: What do you need to save? NSData?

Comment: Yes. I want the "seekToFile", too. And this is why I use NSFileHandle Class. Or should I implement a class myself calling low-level system API like `fseek()`, `fwrite()`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

According to [writeData method Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilehandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileHandle/writeData%3a), this method raises an exception if the file descriptor is closed or is not valid, if the receiver represents an unconnected pipe or socket endpoint, if no free space is left on the file system, or if any other writing error occurs.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I add comment in my question. And that also explains why I did not use `-writeToFile:` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can write any standard cocoa object to a file pretty simple. This returns a BOOL value if it is sucessful or not

```
BOOL result = [YOUR_OBJECT writeToFile:@"absolute/file/path" atomically:YES]];

if (result)
    NSLog(@"All went well");
else
    NSLog(@"File was not saved");
```